# ClassCastException when casting Object to String, but no ClassCastException when casting Object to Custom class

Tags: java

It appears I don't understand basic concept of casting in Java. Please explain why first line is valid and second is not

```
  public int compareTo(Object o) {
        Person p = (Person) o; //no warning
        String s = (String) o; //warning about class cast exception
        return 0;
    }
```

What is the difference here? Why it allows cast object to person?

Comment: Maybe because `Object o` is `Person`?  And it cannot be at the same time the `String` because `String` is final class and `Person` cannot extend it.

Comment: Yes, what Alex said. So the compiler can guarantee that your cast will fail, so it won't allow it.

Answer (score 2):

Try inverting :

```
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    String s = (String) o; //no warning
    Person p = (Person) o; //warning about class cast exception
    return 0;
}
```

You'll get the same warning on the second cast. This is because the sonar linter care about the context : it assume that if your first cast succeeed the second will fail.

Answer (score 0):

I think the compiler will allow this as you said its only a warning. As a cast to a String will only succeed in case its actually a String. In your case, your code will only succeed if o is null, that's probably the reason you get this warning.